# How to merge two datasets, containing the same record with different changes in each one

Tags: .net, merge, dataset

I have DS A and B.
DS A, has a record 1 in table A, with changes in column 1.
DS B, has a the same record 1 in table A, but with changes in column 2 and 3.

If I do A.Merge(B, true); -> I loose the changes made in column 2 and 3, but changes in DS A are preserved, and  viceversa.

Is there any way to do a merge keeping both changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you have to implement this merging yourself (or find somebody who has implemented this).

The dotnet-dataset has two versons of each row: the original and the modified. you can iteate over each column and compare the original with the modified value and react accordingly.